# Why does Selenium's ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xPath))) return a String?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, nosuchelementexception

A **simplified** version of my code.

```
do {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpLucka)));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpLucka)).click();
        System.out.println("Clickable = " + ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpSvar)));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
} while (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpSvar)) == null);
```

I have some issues with clicking on `xpLucka`, it takes several attempts before it succeeds, hence this ugly temporary workaround - but it still fails. In the Javadoc for both `elementToBeClickable` and `visibilityOfElementLocated` (I have exeperimented with both, and a couple of other methods in the same family) it says under `returns`, *the WebElement once it is located and clickable (visible and enabled)* but when I print the value it prints the XPath that I use as a locator (`xpSvar`).

**What am I missing here?** Because, in the next step, where I try to click `xpSvar` I get `NoSuchElementException` - because I am still in the view where I should click `xpLucka`. Clearly `xpLucka` hasn't been clicked and `xpSvar` isn't clickable or visible.

---

Edit: Why would the Xpath matter?

Anyway, here it is *xpLucka* `//div[@class='calendar-scratcher__container ng-scope']//div[@class='calendar-scratcher-field ng-scope ng-isolate-scope calendar-scratcher-field--interact-click']` and *xpSvar* `//ul[@class='question__answers ng-scope question__answers--text question__answers--has-active-state question__answers--align-center']/li[@class='question__answer-item question__answer-item--h6'][x]`

Comment: Can you post the site,the xpath or html code for the element you want.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Added the Xpaths.